# How can I put the results of these 2 queries side by side as one result

Tags: sql, t-sql

The database is Adventureworks 2014 and I'm using 2014 developer edition. I tried `UNION ALL` it didn't work. I also tried something, I think it was join. It combined them into one column witch isn't what I wanted to do.

Id like to combine the 2 below to get this result rather than the 2 as separate results which is what I have currently.

```
YearOfOrderDate   CountOfOrders
2011              1406
2012              3162
2013              11095
2014              10354
```

```
select count(SalesOrderID) as CountOfOrders
from AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by datepart(year,AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate)
order by datepart(year,AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate) 

select datepart(year,OrderDate) as YearOfOrderDate
from AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by datepart(year,AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate)
order by datepart(year,AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate)
```

Comment: cant you just do select datepart(year,OrderDate) as Year,  count(SalesOrderID) as CountOfOrders from Adventure...

Answer (score 5):

Do you want this?

```
select datepart(year,OrderDate) as YearOfOrderDate , count(SalesOrderID) as CountOfOrders
from AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
group by datepart(year,s.OrderDate)
order by datepart(year,s.OrderDate)
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @douglasalderman If this worked you should give the answer a check